# Have a problem with disable button after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable button after click for about 3 sec, I do that but I have a problem, on my web app it's working more than 10 users and I want to resolve that click button when someone click on that button it generate some sort of code, and when 2 users click in same time it generate same code two times.
It's server side web app.

Code bellow

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateCodes", "Index",   FormMethod.Post))
    {
     <div class="box-header">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
    <button type="submit" id="ok" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Generate</button>
      <script>
      var fewSeconds = 5;
      $('#ok').click(function () {
      // Ajax request
      var btn = $(this);
      btn.prop('disabled', true);
      setTimeout(function () {
      btn.prop('disabled', false);
      }, fewSeconds * 1000);
     });
     } </script>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to do that with ajax and jQuery and should this pass to controller?

Comment: Could you provide a prettier code?  
There's even no close tag for `<script>`

Comment: @sdym Sorry for that, I edit my code, you can check it.